# how to pass an interface as a function parameter in hardhat?

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I can do this in foundry

```
store.setMarket(
            "BTC-USD",
            IStore.Market({
                symbol: "BTC-USD",
                feed: btcFeed,
                maxLeverage: 50,
                maxOI: 5000000 * CURRENCY_UNIT,
                fee: 10,
                fundingFactor: 5000,
                minSize: 20 * CURRENCY_UNIT,
                minSettlementTime: 1 minutes
            })
        );
```

so how can i do the same thing in hardhat ?

Comment: you can't pass an interface because interface is an abstract concept. What you need to pass is the address. Having the address you can cast it to any kind of interface